# D3 packed circle children chart with a JS mod of the children array(s)

Tags: json, d3.js, javascript, nvd3.js

I have a D3 zoomable packed circle chart working based upon Mike’s demo:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

In the D3 wiki

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Pack-Layout

I see that one can use

```
pack.children([children])
```

to specify the array for the children, yes?

So, in the demo above, how would someone use that to be able to parse the same demo JSON, but with a key for the children that is “subtype” (or whatever) and not “children”? And what if the children of those children have a different name, ad inifinitum?

After looking at the D3 code, it seems that D3 **really** wants to find, literally,  “children” for these hierarchical packed layouts.

I can live with it, but any help is appreciated to further my present D3 dive.

Thanks!

Comment: Check http://bl.ocks.org/saraquigley/1422184, go alway down to `pack.js`

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @BrainS, but your response about pack.js is vague; are you saying that I should look in the datum for the children array at each level within the d3.json call block? Also, this is another example (like all of them) where the JSON has "name" and "children" up and down the hierarchy. If you replace all the "children" in the JSON with "subthing", or "anything", this example chokes too. Thank you for helping, of course. I'm not seeing where you can "control' what to use as the children if it is not actually and literally named "children".

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand the question very well before. I can't answer that question. But i think you can find a lot of information about d3.js here (just search for what you looking for) http://bl.ocksplorer.org/#/search/d3.layout.pack

Answer (score 1):

Let's say in your flare data your children collection was named bob:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "bob": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "bob": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "bob": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "bob": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
...
```

The modification would simply be:

```
var nodes = pack.children(function(d){
  return d.bob;
}).nodes(root);
```

Now what if you had a different name at each level? First, I would argue this is really a poor structure and you should change the source data.  But what if you can't?  Perhaps something like this would work:

```
var nodes = pack.children(function(d){
  if (d['children'] !== undefined){
    return d['children'];
  } else if (d['bob'] !== undefined){
    return d['bob'];
  }
}).nodes(root);
```

Comment: Than you @Mark. Perfect answer and well stated. And it confirms what I thought, there's a pattern here I'm not seeing to mod this, thank you, and..yeah, isn't it better to tweak the custom data model to begin with rather than NOT letting D3 do its thing.